# Android device registration id not receiving first time

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the following code to register the device

```
   GCMRegistrar.register(HomeActivity.this,GCMIntentService.SENDER_ID);
 String  msgREGID = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(HomeActivity.this);
```

all is working well except one thing it not giving msgREGID for the first time , I mean when i install the application and click on button on which this above method is called but it not giving me the msgREGID for the first time but when i go back and launch my application it giving me the msgREGID.

Please suggest how to achieve it for the first time.

Comment: I think you need to show some more code to see what is going on.  For example GCMResgistrar can not be an instance of the GoogleCloudMessaging class,  since that class has a register method, but it only takes a sender_id, and it has not getTegistrationId method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same thing was happened with me when i i tried for GCM code
after research and after google i got solution from stackoverflow

call the code of getting device id from two separate activity for ex.

if currently your getting device id from Activity "ABC" then call the same code before activity ABC get called

if your jumping to "ABC" from activity "PQR" then call device id getting code from both PQR and ABC

and really it worked for me just try this

Answer (score 0):

It takes some time to generate the regid what youy need to do is, you can see in the GCMintent class you have a method

```
private void handleRegistration(Context context, String regId) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Utils.registrationId = regId;
        SavePreferences("PUSHNOT",regId);
         Log.e("", "registration id : "+regId);


         //sendDeviceIdFuction(context,UtilsGcm.registrationId);


    }
```

here it saves the regid to a preference try to access the regid from that preference and it will solve you problem